# Настройка проекта Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

При создании проекта на С# студия автоматически вставляет следующий код:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
}
```

Как этот код можно видоизменить, например чтобы функция Main не принимала никаких параметров.

Или например как можно сделать, чтобы при создании нового класса студия автоматически добавляла конструктор по умолчанию для класса?

Comment: А зачем? Пользуйтесь сниппетом. Наберите `ctor` и нажмите 2 раза Tab

Comment: Я хочу настроить проект под себя, конструктор это только пример. Хотелось бы еще чтобы у каждого класса явно прописывался спецификатор доступа или чтобы класс сразу же был разбит на регионы, чтобы библиотеки по умолчанию не подключались

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Каждый проект, который вы добавляете в решение - он создаётся из определённого шаблона и вы можете создать свой собственный шаблон.

Для этого создайте пустой проект, отредактируйте его так, как вам будет нужно - а после этого в меню File нажмите Export Template (для VS2015) или запустите мастер из Project - Export Template Wizard (в 2017 версии студии).

По второй части вопроса (шаблон класса) есть [отличный ответ на en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2072687/5752652), выберите свою версию IDE.

Например, для редакции VS 2017 Enterprise см. шаблон:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

Выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [Практическое руководство. Создание шаблонов проектов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates)
- [How to: Create Project Templates in VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)
- [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2072687/5752652)
- [Переменные в шаблонах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx)